# Incompatible element type Decimal for collection of SOBJECT:Operation__c

Tags: apex

Kindly suggest where the above said error is ( I am attempting to do it in Developer console) and its resolution.
Here I am modifying a field FirstInstallmentAmt__c which is in Operation__c by a field in Payment_Details__r (Fees_Received__c) on a condition. Payment_Detail__c (Operation_Number__c is a look-Up field) is a child object of Operation__c.

```
 list<Operation__c> tempOp2 = new list<Operation__c>();
 list<Operation__c> tempOp3 = [Select id, name,FirstInstallmentAmt__c, 
                                (Select id, Operation_Number__c,Fees_Received__c
                                       from Payment_Details__r)
                                from Operation__c];
system.debug('=tempOp3--' + tempOp3);
for(Operation__c temp1 : tempOp3){
     for(Payment_Detail__c pd : temp1.Payment_Details__r){
         if(temp1.FirstInstallmentAmt__c == null &&
             pd.Fees_Received__c != null){
             temp1.FirstInstallmentAmt__c = pd.Fees_Received__c;
             tempOp2.add(temp1.FirstInstallmentAmt__c);
            system.debug('temp1.FirstInstallmentAmt__c--'+temp1.FirstInstallmentAmt__c);
       }
    }
}
update tempOp2;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`tempOp2` is a List of `Operation__c` objects. You are trying to add a Decimal value into it:

```
 list<Operation__c> tempOp2 = new list<Operation__c>();
 ...
 tempOp2.add(temp1.FirstInstallmentAmt__c);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot BarCotter. It was a silly mistake from my side.